# Phonegap Build Background Mode

Tags: ios, html, cordova, phonegap-build

Please note that i have searched thoroughly so do not come here telling to do a search.

Second, this is related to Phonegap Build! Not the CLI!

The Problem:
I have a music app streaming music online, and when the home or power button is pressed, or you navigate to another app, the music stops. Resumes when you come back to the app.

My music player is soundmanager2, an html5 JavaScript app.

I have included this into my **config.xml**:

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode" />
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIBackgroundModes" overwrite="true">
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
    </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

And initialized it in my **index.html**:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
        initPushwoosh();
        StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);

        // window.plugin.notification.local is now available
    }, false);
```

But it still does the same thing. Only deference is i see the play button on the Lockscreen but it does not work or play, but the track url is there so its for the audio. If you understand what i am trying to say.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To close this, for anyone else that might be going through it: use this plugin.

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio" source="npm" />
```